# how to retrieve object at server end in servlet when sent through retrofit using @Body annotation

Tags: java, android, json, servlets, retrofit2

I am sending **Card** object using **retrofit2** from android and i want to save the data of that object at server in a json file. I tried to retrieve the object's data as follows but at server null is returned by this statement:

```
req.getParameter("job_title")
```

So,i want to know how to retrieve the actual values of the object at server end?

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



@WebServlet(name = "save_card" , urlPatterns = "/savecard")
public class SaveCard extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println(req.getParameter("job_title"));
    resp.getWriter().print("true");
}    
}
```

i am using following Card class whose object is to be sent to server

```
package com.go.gocard.model;


import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;



public class Card {

private static final String FIELD_TITLE = "job_title";
private static final String FIELD_MOBILE = "phone";
private static final String FIELD_NAME = "name";
private static final String FIELD_EMAIL = "email";

@SerializedName(FIELD_TITLE)
private String title;
@SerializedName(FIELD_MOBILE)
private String mobile;
@SerializedName(FIELD_NAME)
private String name;
@SerializedName(FIELD_EMAIL)
private String email;

public Card(){

}

public Card(String name, String title, String email,  String mobile) {
    this.title = title;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    title = title;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    mobile = mobile;
}

public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    email = email;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}


@Override
public String toString(){
    return "title = " + title + ", mobile = " + mobile + ", name = " + name + ", email = " + email;
}
}
```

This is the service interface containing service method which is sending object:

```
package com.go.gocard.card;

import com.go.gocard.model.Card;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;


public interface CardService {

@POST("savecard")
Call<String> sendCard(@Body Card card);
}
```

Comment: `Gson gson = new Gson(); Card card = gson.fromJson(req.getReader());`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce second statement is giving error . no suitable method found for fromJson(BufferedReader)

Comment: Oh, it's `gson.fromJson(req.getReader(), Card.class)`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce still card object is null....but i checked that req.getReader().readLine() is returning the actual json object as string which was sent from application

Comment: the problem is in parsing that string representation of json object into Card object

Comment: @EpicPandaForce com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2...this is the exception in server log when parsing

Answer (score 0):

Create JSON string from your class and send it via retrofit as Body. 
You can use [any](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) options to do this and after that, you can send it to the server.

Interface:

```
@POST("savecard")
Call<JsonElement> sendCard(@Body RequestBody card);
}
```

Request:

```
  //resultJson - json in String format, which you create from your class
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), resultJson)
    Call<JsonElement> result = service.sendCard(requestBody);
```

Response:

```
public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, retrofit2.Response<JsonElement> response) {
            JsonElement jsonElement = response.body(); 
            String responseInJson = jsonElement.toString;
}
```